# SQL: Finding how calculations are made every year

Tags: java, sql

I have this data, and I want to know how are pending, hold accepted and rejected in every month and every year.i stored date as string.these details from form.i am using hibernate.

```
request      | status
-----------  | ------
31-7-2017    | pending 
2017-07-26   | accepted
2017-07-29   | hold
31-7-2017    | hold 
31-7-2017    | accepted
31-7-2017    | pending
2017-7-31    | rejected
2017-7-31    | pending
2017-7-31    | accepted
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's **impossible** to tell from your table above, as there's no synonymous point of data. What's the content? Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Where did you get that funky looking date data?  Are you storing your dates as strings?  Which database are using?  Note that date functionality is highly DB specific.

Comment: any other example of what could be the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT  DISTINCT status,
 day(request) , YEAR(request) ,
count(*) FROM
GROUP BY day(request) , YEAR(request) ,status